# How to access the data in this list?

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I am using IMDBpy to fetch release date of an episode of any tv series using this function.

```
episode_Release_date = ia.get_movie_release_dates(episode_id)
```

Now this function is returning this value -

```
{'data': {'raw release dates': [{'country': 'Argentina', 'date': '30 July 2017'}, {'country': 'USA', 'date': '30 July 2017'}, {'country': 'Germany', 'date': '31 July 2017', 'notes': ' (limited)'}, {'country': 'UK', 'date': '31 July 2017'}, {'country': 'Italy', 'date': '31 July 2017'}], 'release dates': ['Argentina::30 July 2017', 'USA::30 July 2017', 'Germany::31 July 2017 (limited)', 'UK::31 July 2017', 'Italy::31 July 2017']}, 'titlesRefs': {}, 'namesRefs': {}, 'info sets': ('release dates', 'akas')}
```

Now I only want data related to USA. How to access USA's release date in this list.

API Function -

```
def get_movie_release_dates(self, movieID):
        cont = self._retrieve(self.urls['movienter code heree_main'] % movieID + 'releaseinfo')
        ret = self.mProxy.releasedates_parser.parse(cont)
        ret['info sets'] = ('release dates', 'akas')
        return ret
```

I'm new to python and just a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pprint` could be helpful in visualizing when navigating nested dictionaries

```
for i in ret['data']['release dates']:
    if 'USA' in i:
        print(i)
# USA::30 July 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like return value is a json string but I am not sure why "(", ")" are present in the returned value. Assuming that it's a proper json value, json module can be used to parse and get the desired value.

If you are searching for raw released dates -

```
for relEntry in episode_Release_date['data']['raw release dates']:
    if relEntry['country'] == "USA":
        print(relEntry)
```

And if you are searching in release dates -

```
for relEntry in episode_Release_date['data']['release dates']:
    if "USA" in relEntry:
        print(relEntry)
```